# why numbered list is called ol in web?

Tags: abbreviations

In Information Technology, there is a technical word `ol` in html code,

Why is numbered list written as `ol`? What does the letter *o* stand for?

Comment: The suitability of this question to this site is marginal at best. It should probably be asked on some other site, though it would probably get closed there too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about abbreviations used in programming.

Comment: @DamkerngT. And it is [general reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html) to boot.

Comment: `ol` is not actually a word, technical or otherwise. It has no part of speech, you can't use it in a sentence (you can *mention* it, but not *use* it), and it's not pronounced how it's spelled.

Answer (score 4):

`ol` stands for *ordered list*. It's an HTML syntax rule.

Answer (score 1):

It's not only in HTML syntax actually, in some other web programming languages like PHP or CSS, they also use **ol** to write *ordered list* or *numbered list* in the User Interface.

The word *ordered* means that the list is written in order (from the smallest to the largest).

You use **ul** to print an **un-ordered list** or the list with no numbers in order (labeled only with bullets or checks.)

Comment: OK then, I've edited the answer, for you. Thank you.